# Session Timeout Spring

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I am making a web application based on Spring 3 and Apache Wicket. When the user of the application click on element, after the timeout of the session, the application crash because the HTML file doesn't find the Java component. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You can redirect to login page

Comment: what wicket version you are using?

Comment: I use Wicket 7.0.2

Comment: There is no version 7.0.2. I guess you mean 7.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Wicket will create a new instance of the page if the old one is gone for any reason: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/38bee6e932e63fa033c2139cdfb2f82eba55fadc/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/settings/PageSettings.java#L46

Maybe this setting is `false` for you ?!

Comment: This solution works for the normal case, but it give me problems when I try to create page from Javascript element using PageParameters.

Comment: Please expand on this! What exactly you do there ?

Comment: Ok with getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(LoginPage.class);
            getPageSettings().setRecreateBookmarkablePagesAfterExpiry(false);            works correctly, because the application force to reconstruct a new fresh version of the page when the session expired

Answer (score 0):

Behind you spring/wicket app you have a Java Servlet Web application. Set the timeout=0 and sessions won't expire.

Include this block in the web.xml. You can also do it programatically.

```
<web-app ...>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `ExpiredErrorPage` Configure below  in `yourApplication` init() method

Whenever session expired it will redirect to `loginpage` . It will not show like crashed .so that you can login again and do your stuff.

```
getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(LoginPage.class);
```

Comment: This works for me fine for most of the page. But I have some pages that includes Panel that goes on error when the user click on some button on the page and the system tries to refresh the page. The error that appears is                                                                             
ERROR: org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer - Unable to find component with id 'BookingSheet' in [Page class = com.lgs.bl.web.PrenotazioneRiepilogo, id = 3, render count = 1]
 Expected: ':BookingSheet'.
 Found with similar names: ''

Comment: @MatteoRossi It looks You are missing `BookingSheet`in your page . But it has nothing to do with session. Its a page error. You need to check in the page itself.

Comment: I know that this error it's a page error. But the problem is that this probelm occurs only when the session is expired and the user click on an element inside the page. The page work correctly in normal case

Comment: @MatteoRossi  i got it but need more information to sorted out your current issue .Update question with more information .